# Nexus directory storage/repositoryName/.nexus/attributes - What is it for?

Tags: maven, nexus

In the storage directory of my Nexus 2.14, the different repositories have subdirectories of the form `/.nexus/attributes` which seem to duplicate a lot of artifacts?

What are they for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are JSON files which hold information about the real artifacts in storage, such as who deployed them, when they were last requested, etc.